# How to Parse JSON Data and display in it in an iPhone Applicaiton

Tags: objective-c, json

I want to parse the following given all the data in and array then use in iPhone application to display.

http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=fullEvents&appid=620

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=fullEvents&appid=620"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

NSDictionary *dictOne = [results objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *activitiesArray = [dictOne objectForKey:@"activities"];

NSDictionary *dictTwo = [activitiesArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *eventDict = [dictTwo objectForKey:@"event"];

NSDictionary *dictThree = [activitiesArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *eventDict3 = [dictThree objectForKey:@"images"];

NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [eventDict3 objectForKey:@"large"]);

NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [eventDict objectForKey:@"category"]);
NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [eventDict objectForKey:@"content"]);
```

Comment: It’d help if you posted a relevant excerpt of your JSON text. At this moment, the server is not returning a response.

Comment: i am posting all the code and you should also check json link file i am posting all the code ok

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine but if I print HoursFrom from dates object it's not printing

That'll be because in your data feed, it's **hoursFrom**, not HoursFrom. The case is significant.

Comment: thanks can you tell me that how may i print all the categories which are in this json now it's only printing only two